# Dans les nues : sens

Tags: vocabulaire, paroles-de-chanson

> Un grand drame à petite échelle au-delà
>   
>  De ce que l'on voit dans les vues
>   
> Voulez-vous dansez, mademoiselle, au-delà
>   
> Le vent nous envoie **dans les nues**
>
> — tiré de « La grande tornade » de Mes Aïeux, 2008 ([paroles](https://genius.com/Mes-aieux-la-grande-tornade-lyrics), [vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp8syQolDE0)).

J'ai des difficultés à trouver un article lexicographique sur « les nues ». L'expression n'apparaît pas [dans le corpus de Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22dans%20les%20nues%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) là non plus.

J'avais pensé à l'adjectif *nu* (peut-être que la nominalisation serait un état de quelque genre ...) mais [la seule paire de traductions sur Linguée](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22dans%20les%20nues%22) voudrait que « les nues » signifie « les nuages ».

Est-ce que c'est la bonne interprétation — et s'agit-il d'une apocope normale ou plutôt rare ?

Comment: Le wiktionaire indique que c’est un altération de "nuages". Cela reste très poétique et à mon sens très rarement utilisé, si ce n’est dans l’expression « tomber des nues ». Je n’en fais pas une réponse car je n’ai malheureusement pas de bonnes références.

Comment: @LaurentS Étrange que j'ai manqué cette référence. C'est donc plus clair que je n'avais cru. Il y a néanmoins assez d'informations dans l'article pour en rédiger une réponse à cette question, si tu voudrais. Sinon je pourrai le faire plus tard.

Comment: Vous avez mis l'expression entre guillemets au _ngram_, qu'il n'a pas digéré... sans guillemets, l'expression sort ! Le lien entre _nue_ et _nuage_ me fait penser au lien entre _vape_ et _vapeur_... Merci !

Comment: @LaurentS. *Nue* n'est pas une altération de *nuage*, c'est le contraire. Nuage est un dérivé de nue qu'il a fini par remplacer.

Comment: @Améraldor Oh, c'est vrai ... En les retirant on voit aussi assez clairement l'histoire de la disparition du mot. Merci !

Comment: Un autre conseil, il vaut mieux choisir le corpus "French" qui est le dernier en date (2012) et le plus exhaustif plutôt que le corpus "French (2009)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nue](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nue/1), [nuée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nu%C3%A9e) et [nuage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nuage) sont tous des descendants du *[nubes](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/nubes)* latin.

Le premier a été supplanté par le dernier sauf dans quelques expressions figées et en poésie.